# sql query on line

Tags: mysql, sql, line, aggregate

I have one SQL table
There are entries

```
+-----------------+------+
| idanother_table | Col1 |
+-----------------+------+
|              11 |   50 |
|              11 |   61 |
|              11 |   62 |
|              12 |   61 |
|              12 |   62 |
|              13 |   50 |
|              13 |   65 |
+-----------------+------+
```

I want a query that gives this result

```
+-----------------+------+
| idanother_table | Col1 |
+-----------------+------+
|              11 |   50 |
|              11 |   61 |
|              11 |   62 |
|              13 |   50 |
|              13 |   65 |
+-----------------+------+
```

So get all lines related to 
`id_anothertable and col1 = 50`.

So when for an id we have col1=50, we take all lines related to that id

Maybe this problem is a duplicate of another, but really i don't know how to name my problem so i have any base for research

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE idanother_table IN 
(
    SELECT idanother_table 
    FROM t
    where Col1 = 50
)
```

or `exists`

```
SELECT * 
FROM t t1 
WHERE exists
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM t tt
    where tt.Col1 = 50 and t1.idanother_table = tt.idanother_table
)
```

Comment: i would use the IN query, MySQL tends to optimize badly when using co-related subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a join on subquery for col1 = 50 retuning idanother_table

```
select * from my_table 
inner join (
    select  idanother_table 
    from my_table  
    where col1 = 50  
) t on t.idanother_table = my_table.idanother_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT idanother_table, Col1 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE idanother_table IN (SELECT idanother_table 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE Col1=50
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
WHERE exists
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM  t2
    where t1.idanother_table =t2.idanother_table and t2.Col1 = 50
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `exists` operator on a query that checks for `col1 = 50`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   mytable b
               WHERE  a.idanother_table = b.idanother_table AND
                      b.col1 = 50)
```